# Search in/for text in files

Tags: powershell-2.0

I am currently learning [LPTHW Ex 46](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex46.html). In his video tutorial, Zed had done the following commands:

1. Find NAME within files using `grep -r "NAME" *`.
2. Find all files with extension ending in .pyc using `find . -name "*pyc" -print`.

Unfortunately, the above code does not work on Windows PowerShell. May I know what their Windows PowerShell equivalents are?

Based on my search, item 1 can be replaced by [`Select-String`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730968.aspx). However, it is not as good as we can only search specific files and not directories. For example, while this would work:

```psh
Select-String C:\Users\KMF\Exercises\Projects\gesso\gesso\acrylic.py -pattern "NAME"
```

this would not:

```psh
Select-String C:\Users\KMF\Exercises\Projects\gesso -Pattern "NAME"
```

and it gives the following error

> Select-String : The file C:\Users\KMF\Exercises\Projects\gesso can not be read: Access to the path 'C:\Users\KMF\Exercises\Projects\gesso' is denied.

For item 2 I could not find a similar function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grep` and `find` are Unix/Linux shell commands. They won't work in PowerShell unless you install a Windows port of them.

As you already found out, `Select-String` is the PowerShell equivalent for `grep`. It doesn't recurse by itself, though, so you have to combine it with `Get-ChildItem` to emulate `grep -r`:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Select-String -Pattern 'NAME'
```

For emulating `find` you'd combine `Get-ChildItem` with a `Where-Object` filter:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.Extension -eq '.pyc' }
```

---

PowerShell cmdlets can be aliased to help administrators avoid extensive typing (since PowerShell statements tend to be rather verbose). There are several built-in aliases, e.g. `ls` or `dir` for `Get-ChildItem`, and `?` or `where` for `Where-Object`. You can also define aliases of your own, e.g. `New-Alias -Name grep -Value Select-String`. Parameter names can be shortened as long as the truncated parameter name remains unique for the cmdlet. When cmdlets allow positional parameters they can even be omitted entirely.

With all of the above your two PowerShell statements can be reduced to the following:

```
ls -r | grep 'NAME'
ls -r | ? { $_.Extension -eq '.pyc' }
```

Note however, that aliases and abbreviations are mainly intended as an enhancement for console use. For PowerShell scripts you should always use the full form, not only for readability, but also because aliases may differ from environment to environment. You don't want your scripts to break just because they're run by someone else.

Comment: Hi Ansgar, thanks alot for the reply. With regards to the setting of New-Alias, may I know whether it is necessary to specify the -Name and the -Value? Based on reading this [link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d1bfde3f-e2ed-47bd-a178-602fae772387) it doesn't seem to be necessary. Also, is there a way to shorten this method of recursively deleting all *.pyc from a folder `get-childitem -include *.pyc -recurse | foreach ($_) {remove-item $_.fullname}` @Ansgar Wiechers

Comment: @ferry `-Name` and `-Value` are not required. Like I said, many cmdlets accept positional parameters as well. As for your other question, yes that can be shortened as well. You don't even need the `foreach`, because `Remove-Item` accepts pipeline input. One of its aliases is `rm`.